# Android bitmap image

Tags: android, bitmap

I am new to android development . 
I would like to know how i can modify an image selected by the user from gallery. 
Is it possible to do this by getting the image using "File Input Stream"?
Or should i use Bitmap?

Answer (score 1):

Create a canvas object from the respective Bitmap.
All editing can be done on the canvas instance and will be applied to the bitmap Object.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Aviary SDK](http://www.aviary.com/android). It also support iOS and WindowPhone7. Aviary provide most of function such as Orientation, Crop, and Sharpness,Red-Eye, Whiten, and Blemish,Stickers, Drawing, Text, and Meme (beta),Brightness, Saturation, and Contrast and custom Options.

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class ProcessingImage {
private Bitmap defaultImg;
private int idBitmap;

public int getIdBitmap() {
    return idBitmap;
}

public void setIdBitmap(int idBitmap) {
    this.idBitmap = idBitmap;
}

public Bitmap getDefaultImg() {
    return defaultImg;
}

public void setDefaultImg(Bitmap defaultImg) {
    this.defaultImg = defaultImg;
}

public ProcessingImage() {
}

public Bitmap processingI(Bitmap myBitmap) {
    return myBitmap;
}

public Bitmap TintThePicture(int deg, Bitmap defaultBitmap) {

    int w = defaultBitmap.getWidth();
    int h = defaultBitmap.getHeight();

    int[] pix = new int[w * h];
    defaultBitmap.getPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

    double angle = (3.14159d * (double) deg) / 180.0d;
    int S = (int) (256.0d * Math.sin(angle));
    int C = (int) (256.0d * Math.cos(angle));

    int r, g, b, index;
    int RY, BY, RYY, GYY, BYY, R, G, B, Y;

    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            index = y * w + x;
            r = (pix[index] >> 16) & 0xff;
            g = (pix[index] >> 8) & 0xff;
            b = pix[index] & 0xff;
            RY = (70 * r - 59 * g - 11 * b) / 100;
            BY = (-30 * r - 59 * g + 89 * b) / 100;
            Y = (30 * r + 59 * g + 11 * b) / 100;
            RYY = (S * BY + C * RY) / 256;
            BYY = (C * BY - S * RY) / 256;
            GYY = (-51 * RYY - 19 * BYY) / 100;
            R = Y + RYY;
            R = (R < 0) ? 0 : ((R > 255) ? 255 : R);
            G = Y + GYY;
            G = (G < 0) ? 0 : ((G > 255) ? 255 : G);
            B = Y + BYY;
            B = (B < 0) ? 0 : ((B > 255) ? 255 : B);
            pix[index] = 0xff000000 | (R << 16) | (G << 8) | B;
        }
    }

    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, defaultBitmap.getConfig());
    bm.setPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

    pix = null;
    return bm;
}
}
```